# Nested conditionals break within low_search:results tag

Tags: low-search

ee v2.9.2
low search v4.4.0

The code below is generating an error:

> You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.
>
> Parser State: Unexpected end of Template “image-database/results” on line 93; expected ENDIF tag for opening on line 91.

Removing the {low_search:results} tags, the error goes away.

Removing the {if no_results} conditional, the error goes away.

Removing the {if count ==1} conditional, the error goes away.

Removing the {if category_is_parent == 0} conditional, the error goes away.

Removing the {nsm_categories:archive tags}, the error remains.

```
{exp:low_search:results
    query="{segment_3}"
    collection="image-gallery"
    paginate="bottom"
    limit="28"
    orderby_sort="low_search_collection:image-gallery"
    require_all="category"
    }
    {if no_results}
        {exp:nsm_categories:archive
            enable=""
            category_group="8" depth="2"
            start_at_category="58"
            style="linear"
            }
            {if count ==  1}abc{/if}
                {if category_is_parent != 0}
                    {category_name}
                {/if}
                {if category_is_parent == 0}
                    {if count ==  1}yes{if:else}no{/if}
                {/if}
            {if count == total_results}xyz{/if}
        {/exp:nsm_categories:archive}
    {/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

I am convinced the issue with Low Search but I am not an expert.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I doubt this is a Low Search issue.

If the problem persists if you change the `exp:low_search:results` tag to a `exp:channel:entries` tag, then the issue is definitely not related to LS. Can you check if this is the case?

You can also try and use `{if low_search_no_results}` rather than `{if no_results}`, to see if that makes a difference. It's probably due to unexpected nesting that the error is thrown.

You can even try and move the code inside the no_results conditional into an embed and see if it works that way.

Side note: you're targeting a single collection, so using `orderby_sort="low_search_collection:image-gallery"` is not necessary. You can safely remove that parameter.

Comment: The problem does persist when I change  exp:low_search:results tag to a  exp:channel:entries tag.

Comment: The problem persists if I use 'if low_search_no_results'.

Comment: I didn't try the embed. (I ended up with a work around because I wanted a different UX.)